# How to select field in another table join by eager loading in Laravel

Tags: laravel-4, eloquent

I got category_to_news and news_main table

**category_to_news**

- news_id int
- name varchar
- title timestamp

**news_main**

- id int
- title varchar
- image varchar
- created_at timestamp

how to return by news_main's field and category_news's field ? I've tried this method and it's not work

```
$posts = Categorytonews::with(array(
    'Newsmain' => function($query)
    {
        $query->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->select(array('title', 'id', 'created_at', 'image'));
    }
    ))
    ->get( );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$posts = Categorytonews::with(array('Newsmain' => function($query)
{
    $query->select(array('title', 'id', 'created_at', 'image'))->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
}))->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need join for this because with() runs another query, so ordering there won't do the job:

```
$posts = Categorytonews::with('Newsmain') // get all fields from Newsmain
  ->join('news_main', 'category_to_news.news_id', '=', 'news_main.id') // join for ordering
  ->orderBy('news_main.id','desc') // order by joined field
  ->get('category_to_news.*'); // select only main table, you don't need joined fields
                               // on Categorytonews model - they will be loaded by with()
```